# operation is cancelled for AFHTTPRequestOperation class in AFNetworking library for IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, file-upload, afnetworking

I want to upload multiple videos using AFNetworking. I have prepared one singleton class like :

@interface MFMediaFactoryAPIClient : AFHTTPClient{
}
Using this class, I'm uploading multiple photos or videos using below method :

```
- (void)postPathWithMultipleRequests:(NSString *)path 
                       requestsArray:(NSMutableArray *)requestsArray 
                             success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                             failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure uploadProgressBlock:(void (^)(NSInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite))uploadProgressBlock

{  

// I have written one loop for preparing  request object. In loop i also written below code.

                AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

                [operation setUploadProgressBlock:uploadProgressBlock];
                [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:success failure:failure];

                [self enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];

}
```

Basically, I'm preparing one operation for upload video and add it to operationQueue by using method :
 enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation.

But Main problem is that operation is running for some time i.e. uploading is continued for some time but when i change tab (I'm using tab bar application and when i tap then from each tab web service request is made using above class) and send other request then above operation is being cancelled somehow and I can't able to upload video.

Please help or suggest me what i can do to avoid this problem ?

For uploading multiple photos or videos is there any other better way then please suggest !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make that object of AFHTTPRequestOperation in Appdelegate ,so it will become global.so when it will start requests , it will not stop untill you forcefully stops it..

May be this help....

let me know is it working or not!!!!!!

Happy Coding.....!!!!

Comment: I think It must be local because it's not one operation..It's like when user uploads 10 files then 10 times this object is created and it's added to operationQueue.